# How to update a ListView with a Button click in different pages?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, binding, uwp

I've two different XAML Pages, in the first one I've a Button and in the other page a ListView. I've already done some binding stuff and create a "Model" class.
This is my ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListaEventos" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Eventos}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Emoji">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Evento">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Minuto}" Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Segundo}" Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Icono}" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Accion}" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Equipo}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

And this is my Model class:

```
public class Evento
{
    public string Minuto { get; set; }

    public string Segundo { get; set; }

    public string Icono { get; set; }

    public string Accion { get; set; }

    public string Equipo { get; set; }

}
```

Finally, I've a Button in other page and I want to add an item, something like this:

```
Eventos.Add(new Evento { Minuto = "10", Segundo = "00", Icono = "", Accion="Triple de", Equipo=" Visitante" });
```

I've done a lot of research but I haven't found any useful information or similar simple. Please upvote, I need your help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can define a static `ObservableCollection` to add the new item in other page.  We can not bind the `ListView` to the static `ObservableCollection` that we can override the `OnNavigatedTo` event and set the static `ObservableCollection` to the `Eventos`.

For example:

```
public static  ObservableCollection<Evento> StaticEvento;
public  ObservableCollection<Evento> Eventos { get; set; }
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    if (StaticEvento == null)
    {
        StaticEvento = new ObservableCollection<Evento>();
        StaticEvento.Add(new Evento { Minuto = "20", Segundo = "00", Icono = "", Accion = "Triple de", Equipo = " Visitante" });
        Eventos = StaticEvento;
    }
}
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Eventos = StaticEvento;
}
```

Another page:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainPage.StaticEvento.Add(new Evento { Minuto = "10", Segundo = "00", Icono = "", Accion = "Triple de", Equipo = " Visitante" });
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    rootFrame.GoBack();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me because the page of the button appears BEFORE the ListView page so it throw me this exception "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"

Comment: @PabloJiménezPascual If you do not load the ListView page at first, you should be able to instantiate the static `ObservableCollection` before you add new item to it.

Comment: Thanks, I finally managed to do it declaring "StaticEvento" in the Button's page and changing a little bit of the code in order to fit well with my case.